# Maven shade plugin not relocating

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-shade-plugin

I've been trying to shade a package from one jar into my own and when I build the project using IntelliJ, it does not shade it in. I've been trying different things from online for over an hour and I thought it would be much simpler to ask on here. I have Maven 3.5.0 installed (`mvn -version` returns the proper version) and I can see the jar I'm trying to shade in the repositories directory.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mccraftaholics</groupId>
<artifactId>WarpPortals</artifactId>
<version>5.6.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>WarpPortals</name>
<url>http://alexwendland.com</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>bstats-repo</id>
        <url>http://repo.bstats.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bstats</groupId>
        <artifactId>bstats-bukkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>org.bstats:*</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.bstats</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>com.mccraftaholics.warpportals</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you please post the error logs after performing the maven goals like clean install?

Comment: Not supported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93855.

Comment: I was able to do it through command line. Thanks!